# Get ngrepeat $index with getElementById()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and I am curious on what is the best approach to getting then index of an ngrepeat on an input and comparing to see if the new string is different from the original value:

js:

```
var checkIfDataSampleHasChanged = document.getElementById('dsField' + i).value;
     console.log(checkIfDataSampleHasChanged);
     console.log($scope.currentSchema)
     if (checkIfDataSampleHasChanged != $scope.currentSchema.sDataSamples.dsName) {
       console.log("hello there")
       $scope.currentSchema.sDataSamples.dsName = checkIfDataSampleHasChanged;
     }
```

html:

```
  <fieldset ng-repeat="ds in currentSchema.sDataSamples track by $index">
  <label for="{{dsField$index}}" style="width:400px;">
    Data Sample Name ({{ds.dsFileName}}):</label>
  <input name="{{dsField$index}}" type="text" style="width: 400px;" ng-model="currentSchema.sDataSamples[$index].dsName" value="{{ds.dsName}}" />
  <br>
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I assume this is in a form and that you want to run this against all the inputs on submit. That being the case - you could just pass the form as a param into the submit function and you can access all of its members individually and compare them to their original data counterpart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a data to hold the initial value and then compare the changed value. You can do this in pure angularjs constructs without using `document.getElementById` and other hacks:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
  var initialSample = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Abc'},
      {id: 2, name: 'def'},
      {id: 3, name: 'ghi'},
      {id: 4, name: 'jkl'},
      {id: 5, name: 'mno'}
  ];
    $scope.sample = angular.merge([], initialSample);
  
    $scope.checkIfValueChanged = function ($index) {
      var isValChanged = initialSample[$index].name !== $scope.sample[$index].name;
      console.log(isValChanged);
      if (isValChanged) {
        alert("Value has changed");
      } else {
        alert("Value has not changed");
      }
    };
  
    $scope.changeVal = function(){
      var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
      console.log(randInt);
      $scope.sample[randInt].name = "Lorem ipsum";
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='AppController'>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in sample" ng-click="checkIfValueChanged($index)">
        {{item.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <button ng-click="changeVal()"> Change random value </button>
  </div>
```